Увеличение дискового пространства через gparted
Увеличил место через менеджер VirtualBox и теперь пытаюсь увеличить место в самой машине.
Для этого запустил grapted

Но при попытке отключить подкачку выдает следующее

Есть ли способы увеличить размер диска без размонтирования каталога /dev/sda6 (home)

Загрузиться с livecd и сделать всё из него. Или перезагрузиться в single user mode, но там придётся всё делать из консоли.

Перед любыми манипуляциями с файловой системой, обязательно сделать резервную копию диска!!! 

Самый простой и не задумчивый способ переустановить операционную
систему. :)
Внимательно проверить корневую директорию и понять от чего система
пухнет, директории занимающие макс размер перенести в другой
раздел(ы) и отредактировать fstab.
Самый медленный вариант двигать разделы

